# PHP code not working - if and redirecting to a page

Tags: php

I am new to php and I wrote this code:

```
<?php

$usernametest="Testing";
$passwordtest="TestingPass";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ((isset($_POST['username']) == $usernametest ) && (isset($_POST['password']) == $passwordtest ))
    { include ('templates/main.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "please enter the correct username and password combination";
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

I made 2 text boxes and a submit button, I want the user to be directed to another page if the username equals Testing and the password equals TestingPass, and if the user doesnt type in the right combination I want the site to say the username and pass are incorrect. Also, where am I supposed to paste this code exactly? above the text boxes codes ?

Comment: "enter code here" part of your code?

Comment: use header() function for redirection like this:  header('location: templates/main.php');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`header()`](http://php.net/header). You should therefore not have an include in that condition, as headers will already be sent.

```
<?php

$usernametest="Testing";
$passwordtest="TestingPass";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if ($_POST['username'] == $usernametest && $_POST['password'] == $passwordtest)
{

header("Location: MY_PAGE.php");
}
else
{
echo "please enter the correct username and password combination";
}
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm new so my reputation level doesn't allow me to, I checked the green check thingy .. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have error in condition checking and redirecting:

```
<?php

    $usernametest="Testing";
    $passwordtest="TestingPass";

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if ((isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $usernametest ) && (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == $passwordtest ))
        { 
           header('location: templates/main.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "please enter the correct username and password combination";
        }
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isset() function checks if variable exists and returns boolean. You must check equality like this:

```
if ($_POST['username'] == $usernametest && $_POST['password'] == $passwordtest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always store values in variable to make code more understandable

```
<?php
```

$usernametest="Testing";
$passwordtest="TestingPass";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

```
   $username    =   $_POST['username'];
   $password    =   $_POST['password'];

if ($username == $usernametest && $password == $passwordtest ))
{       header("location:templates/main.php"); 
}
else
{
    echo "please enter the correct username and password combination"; exit();
}
```

}
?>